# Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I'm trying to use the PayPal-PHP-SDK to integrate PayPal with a custom built WordPress eCommerce theme and I'm getting a an error:

> Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/...

This error only appears when I which to live, it works completely fine on sandbox mode.

On the client side I'm using checkout.js and redirecting it to the PHP file where I'm trying to use the the PayPal-PHP-SDK to execute the payment and I get the error where the code reads:

```
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
```

Below is a **sample code** I am using

**JavaScript**

```
paypal.Button.render({
env: 'production',

client: {
    sandbox: 'sandbox_id',
    production: 'production_id'
},

locale: 'en_US',

style: {
    color: 'blue',
    size: 'responsive',
},

commit: true,

payment: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
            redirect_urls: {
                return_url: site_url + '/execute-payment'
            },

            transactions: [{
                amount: {
                    total: '0.01',
                    currency: 'NZD',
                    details: {
                        subtotal: '0.01',
                        shipping: '0.00',
                        tax: '0.00',
                        insurance: '0.00'
                    }
                },
                description: "TEST",
                invoice_number: json.invoice_number ? json.invoice_number : "",
                item_list: {
                    items: items_ ? items_ : "",
                    shipping_address: {
                        "recipient_name": json.recipient_name ? json.recipient_name : "",
                        "line1": json.line1 ? json.line1 : "",
                        "line2": json.line2 ? json.line2 : "",
                        "city": json.city ? json.city : "",
                        "country_code": json.country_code ? json.country_code : "",
                        "postal_code": json.postal_code ? json.postal_code : "",
                        "phone": json.phone ? json.phone : "",
                        "state": json.state ? json.state : ""
                    }
                }
            }],
            "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
        }
    });
},

onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

    console.log('::Authorized: ');

    return actions.redirect();

},

onCancel: function (data, actions) {
    
    console.log('::Canceled: ');

    /* window.location = "/paypal/cancel/"; */

},

onError: function (error) {

    console.log('::Error: ', error)

}
}, '#paypal_container');
```

**PHP**

```
# live client id
$live_cid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
# live secret id
$live_sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        $live_cid,
        $live_sid
    )
);

$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG',
        'mode' => 'live'
    )
);

# die(var_dump($apiContext));

# redirect here via link: https://example.com/execute-payment/?paymentId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&PayerID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# die(var_dump("<br><br>" . "paymentId: " . $_GET['paymentId'] . "<br>" . "PayerID: " . $_GET['PayerID']));

$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$amount = new Amount();
$details = new Details();

$details->setShipping(0.00)
        ->setTax(0.00)
        ->setSubtotal(0.01);

$amount->setCurrency('NZD');
$amount->setTotal(0.01);
$amount->setDetails($details);
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$execution->addTransaction($transaction);

$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);

# I get the error after trying to execute the payment

$paymentId = $result->id;
$PayerID = $result->payer->payer_info->payer_id;

die(var_dump($result));
```

**Error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute. in /mnt/stor10-wc1-ord1/825767/984521/www.example.com/web/content/newww/wp-content/themes/example/framework/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:207 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/stor10-wc1-ord1/825767/984521/www.example.com/web/content/newww/wp-content/themes/example/framework/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(78): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"payer_id":"66...') #1 /mnt/stor10-wc1-ord1/825767/984521/www.example.com/web/content/newww/wp-content/themes/example/framework/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(104): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"payer_id":"66...', Array) #2 /mnt/stor10-wc1-ord1/825767/984521/www.example.com in /mnt/stor10-wc1-ord1/825767/984521/www.example.com/web/content/newww/wp-content/themes/example/framework/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 207

The above code is part of an old code that was on the website, I'm just trying to make it work. It was working fine until we changed the Client and Secret ID. The payment is being created fine but the issue comes when I execute the payment

**PayPal.log**

```
[05-08-2020 08:51:12] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
[05-08-2020 08:51:13] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[05-08-2020 08:51:13] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[05-08-2020 08:51:14] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[05-08-2020 08:51:14] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute
[05-08-2020 08:51:14] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 404
[05-08-2020 08:51:14] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 404 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute. {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"acba76cd232a5"}


[05-08-2020 08:55:31] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
[05-08-2020 08:55:33] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[05-08-2020 08:55:34] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[05-08-2020 08:55:36] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[05-08-2020 08:55:40] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute
[05-08-2020 08:55:42] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 404
[05-08-2020 08:55:42] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 404 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute. {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"3c22c723fa27a"}
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to guess at what precisely is wrong with the execute call without seeing the full API response body and headers, including a PayPal-Debug-ID

400 errors are usually a wrong credential problem, or credentials paired with the wrong environment, but that is less likely if your payment creation and oauth2 calls are working okay

The more important question is why are you using an deprecated V1 SDK, at all, which is no longer maintained? You should completely change your integration to the current V2 PHP SDK, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/

---

The current best front-end experience to pair it with is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thank you for the reply Preston.

The thing is, the above code is part of an old code that was on the website, I'm just trying to make it work.

It was working fine until we changed the Client and Secret ID.

The payment is being created fine but the issue comes when I execute the payment.

Comment: Alright, well if you log the body of the 400 response we might be able to know something about its cause

Comment: Hi Preston, I have updated the description above, if you could grab a look. Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that you are using the same clientid/secret everywhere? Based on the invalid resource ID error it seems you might be using e.g. a different pair in the JS create than in the execute code

Comment: And if that is the not issue, the second thing to check is whether you are using a stale PAYID-####### .  It needs to be a freshly created and approved one.

Comment: The client / secret id is correct and even the PAYID-###### generated are different every time ..

One of the other errors logged were: 

`[04-08-2020 13:52:10] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-#####/execute. {"name":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","message":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"ae3e56b18b097"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219228/discussion-between-vikash-chand-and-preston-phx).